# How do I set default configuration value in Symfony2 correctly?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, configuration-files

I've built a service which I'd like to be able to configure from a config file.  I've been able to get it working as needed, but when I look at other bundles, don't see the same config setup as I've had to use.  I feel like it's a hack.
What I need is to have a configuration value as optional, meaning if it isn't in the config.yml file it uses a default value.  I've accomplished this by adding the following to my Configuration.php bundle file:

```
namespace ChrisJohnson00\ApiProfilerBundle\DependencyInjection;

...
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('chris_johnson00_api_profiler');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('warning_threshold')
                ->info('Changes the warning threshold time (ms).  This is used to change the toolbar to yellow when the total response time is > this value')
                ->example("5000")
                ->defaultValue("5000")
                ->end()
            ->scalarNode('error_threshold')
                ->info('Changes the error threshold time (ms).  This is used to change the toolbar to red when the total response time is > this value')
                ->example("10000")
                ->defaultValue("10000")
                ->end()
        ->end()
    ;

    return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

But this didn't work alone, I had to add the following to my bundle extension file's load function

```
namespace ChrisJohnson00\ApiProfilerBundle\DependencyInjection;

...
class ChrisJohnson00ApiProfilerExtension extends Extension
{

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config        = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $container->setParameter('chris_johnson00_api_profiler.warning_threshold', $config['warning_threshold']);
        $container->setParameter('chris_johnson00_api_profiler.error_threshold', $config['error_threshold']);

        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');
    }
}
```

How can I configure my bundle's configuration parameters without the need for `$container->setParameter(...)` in my extension file?

Answer (score 0):

Found a cookbook with the answers... I'm doing it correctly it seems.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html